# JQuery Enlarge/Shrink Related Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var up_vote_button = $('.up-vote-button');
var down_vote_button = $('.down-vote-button');

$(up_vote_button).click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('i').css('font-size', '16px');
    $(this).parent().siblings('down-vote')
    .find('i').css('font-size', '14px');        
});                                                                                                                                        
$(down_vote_button).click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('i').css('font-size', '16px');
    $(this).parent().siblings('up-vote')
    .find('i').css('font-size', '14px');        
});

<div class="votes-container">    
    <div class="up-vote">
        <i></i>
        <input class="up-vote-button" type="button" />
    </div>
    <div class="down-vote">
        <i></i>
        <input class="down-vote-button" type="button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this not toggling the font-sizes of related icons. The HTML has been added per the request in comment. Thanks!

Comment: _"Why is this not toggling the font-sizes of related icons?"_ Can you include `html` at Question? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `.` at `.siblings()` selector at each `.click()` handler

```js
var up_vote_button = $('.up-vote-button');
var down_vote_button = $('.down-vote-button');

up_vote_button.click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('i').css('font-size', '16px');
    $(this).parent().siblings('.down-vote')
    .find('i').css('font-size', '14px');        
});                                                                                                                                        
down_vote_button.click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('i').css('font-size', '16px');
    $(this).parent().siblings('.up-vote')
    .find('i').css('font-size', '14px');        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="votes-container">    
    <div class="up-vote">
        <i>up</i>
        <input class="up-vote-button" type="button" />
    </div>
    <div class="down-vote">
        <i>down</i>
        <input class="down-vote-button" type="button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```